# How can I change the order of messages in Mail for Lion?

Tags: macos, mail.app

Suddenly the most recent message in Mail is at the bottom of the list instead of the top. How do I change the ordering of messages?

I am using Mac OS X 10.7.5, Lion.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out; if I go to "View," there's a "sort by" option. Thanks for bearing with me!